# How to change a component on the basis of the link clicked by react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, web-development-server

Please have a look at this code and tell me if you can help me on how can I fix it ,

```
import React from 'react';
import  {Switch, Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Link} from "react-router-dom";




function App(){
return(
    <Router>
        <div className = "sidebar">
            <Link to = "/"><h1 className = "heading ">TODOS</h1></Link>
            <Link to= "/login"> <span className = "links login">LogIn</span></Link>
            <Link to = "/signup"><span className = "links signup">SignUp</span></Link>
            <Link to = "contact"><span className = "links contact">Contact Us</span></Link>
            <Link to = "/about"><span className = "links about">About Developer</span></Link>
        </div>
        <Switch>
            <Route path = "/">
                <h1>home route</h1>
            </Route>
            <Route path = "/login">
                {/* <Login/> */}
                <div>
                 <h1>this is login route</h1>
                </div>
            </Route>    
            <Route path = "/signup">
                <h1>signup page</h1>
            </Route>
            <Route path = "/contact">
                <h1>contact page</h1>
            </Route>
            <Route path = "/about">
                <h1>About page</h1>
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
)
}

export default App;
```

NMw doesn't matter which links you click it shows the same text how can I fix this ??
For testing and a better understanding of question you guys can please go on [this](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/custom-link)  link here and just copy-paste my code and it runs there and please let me know my mistake

Comment: Add `exact` prop on all the Routes (but not in those having nested routes).

Comment: Maybe you can also just move index route to the bottom so that his is a catch-all match on `/` instead of doing exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add exact prop to **all** Route Component. It will work

```
<Route exact path='/yourpath' />
```